# css - center horizontal menu item

Tags: css, menu

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I have created a jsfiddle for the code - http://jsfiddle.net/dfo44q7f/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="/">Menu1</a></li>
  <li><a href="/Menu2/">Menu2</a></li>
  <li><a href="/Menu3/">Menu3</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

how do i?

- Center the text in the li?

Comment: The text is centered in the list element. It just doesn't look like it because you put a lot of padding on the left.

Answer (score 0):

change the padding on:

```
.nav a
```

for:

```
padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
```

or:

```
padding: 10px 40px 10px 40px;
```

The second value is for right padding and the fourth is for left padding, you will have to set them to the same value if you want it to be centered.

Comment: thanks all for the answering it.  i updated the code.. http://jsfiddle.net/dfo44q7f/3/  my question is how do you add padding to the left and right of the menu item without changing the width of the bottom border underneath the text?

Comment: @Lacer you will have to add the padding to right and left, here I modified the padding http://jsfiddle.net/dfo44q7f/4/